# Change 1.0, 2.0 like float values to 1 , 2 | remove trailing zeros from floating binary point types

Tags: java, string, int, double

I am receiving `double` values from API call .That method return this kind of values `2.0`, `2.344`, `2.034`, `3.1` etc.

If  I receive value like `2.0`, `4.0`, I want to convert them `2`, `4`. And I need do this conversions only `2.0`, `3.0` like values.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Sounds like you should be looking at `DecimalFormat`, assuming you're talking about formatting the `double` values as strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not use `float` or `double` to store because they are floating binary point types and will result in `1.0`, `2.0`, etc. You can use `String` to store a formatted value:

```
double myDouble = 3.0D;
String i = myDouble == 0.0 ? "0" : myDouble / Math.floor(myDouble) == 1.0 ? String.format("%.0f", myDouble) : String.valueOf(myDouble);
System.out.println(i);
```

Comment: I think it would be *much* more sensible to use a `DecimalFormat` which omits trailing digits. There are way too many potential problems with the way you're currently doing it, IMO. (I'd also advise against using `"" + ...` as a way of converting a value into a string - the code uses an empty string and string concatenation, neither of which is relevant. I'd use `String.valueOf(...)` which says exactly what you're trying to achieve.)

Comment: @JonSkeet *[String conversion applies only to an operand of the binary + operator which is not a String when the other operand is a String.](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html)*

Comment: I'm not what you think the relevance of that is.

Comment: @JonSkeet You may wanna consider removing your downvote now.

Comment: No, because I still think that's a poor way of checking for an integer, and this sort of string handling is worse than using the dedicated formatting mechanism of `DecimalFormat`.

Comment: @JonSkeet Your code also fails to do it, what I am trying to say is this: My code works for `0.9999999999999999D` and your code also works fine for it but fails when literal is `0.99999999999999999D` for both the answers. You may try it.

Comment: That example isn't a failure of either - 0.99999999999999999D is equal to 1.0, because there's no closer double to 0.99999999999999999.

Comment: I don't see how that question relates to my comment. My comment is just on the precision limit on `double` - that's really not got much to do with formatting.

Comment: Your answer does fail for a value of 0 though... precisely because you're trying to check for it being an integer via division.

Comment: @JonSkeet Yeah, that's a valid point, but frankly I don't see any more problems now.

Comment: Have you considered very carefully the impact of large floating point values and what division might do? Floating point arithmetic is notoriously fiddly with lots of corner cases to consider. I don't see any advantage in using this kind of code over using a class that is designed specifically for formatting.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming this is a matter of *formatting* a `double` value as a `String`, ensuring there are no trailing insignificant zeroes, I'd advise using a `DecimalFormat` to control the formatting. For example:

```
import java.text.*;
import java.util.*;

class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        print(5.0d);
        print(5.000000001d);
        print(5.1d);
        print(123456789.1d);
        print(12345e-50);
    }

    private static void print(double value) {
        NumberFormat format = new DecimalFormat(
            "0.############",
            DecimalFormatSymbols.getInstance(Locale.US));
        String text = format.format(value);
        System.out.println(text);
    }
}
```

Note the use of `Locale.US` to always end up with a dot as the decimal separator.

The final example in `main` shows the limitations here - numbers very close to 0 will be formatted as "0", as I haven't provided enough optional digits (the `#` parts) to format them more appropriately. It's not clear what you want in those cases anyway though; the default representation would be `1.2345E-46`.

Comment: I notice this method very simple than answer one. can you ,please explain, internal behavior  of this method. ?

Comment: @uma: I don't know the internals of DecimalFormat - I just go by its documented behaviour. I assume it works correctly, which means we can get it to do what we want :)